# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open c# asp.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have an asp.net web application which connects to a database using ado.net. 
I've a class-level variable with my connection,then I opened my connection before I make command excutions and I closed this properly but I'm getting an error with my connection. I've put the image of my error.

[image: Image of the runtime error]

```
    SqlConnection sc = new    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            string studentid = Session["student_id"].ToString();

        string i = studentid;
        sc.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("atend", sc);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", studentid);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string subject;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Subject Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Total Lectures");
        table.Columns.Add("Attend Lectures");
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
            dataRow["subject Name"] = rdr["subject_id"];
            subject = rdr["subject_id"].ToString();
            dataRow["Total Lectures"] = gettotalatlectures(subject, studentid);
            dataRow["Attend Lectures"] = getattendance(subject, studentid);
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        sc.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();   
    }

    public int getattendance(string sub, string rollno)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select active from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'",sc);
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int present=0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string x = rdr["active"].ToString();
            if (x == "True")
            {
                present++;
            }

        }
        sc.Close();
        return present;

    }
    public int gettotalatlectures(string sub, string rollno)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'", sc);
        sc.Open();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sc.Close();
        return x;

    }
```

Comment: In the future - instead of taking a screen shot of the error, please copy and paste the error text here. It helps other users searching for the same error to find the posts and it's easier on the people trying to help out.

Answer (score 1):

The explenation is self explanatory.

When you enter `dataRow["Total Lectures"] = gettotalatlectures(subject, studentid);` the connection is open.

So 'f course when you try to open the same connection, he will give this error.
And instead of opening a second connection or even a second command, I would advice to improve your query or stored procedure `(see join / group by / with / ...)` to return this information as well.

This will save you a lit of time and trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open an opened connection. Check your methods **gettotalatlectures** and **getattendance**. 
Remove the open and close of these methods.
Something like this:

```
public int gettotalatlectures(string sub, string rollno)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'", sc);
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        return x;

    }

public int getattendance(string sub, string rollno)
{
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select active from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'",sc);
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int present=0;
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        string x = rdr["active"].ToString();
        if (x == "True")
        {
            present++;
        }

    }
    return present;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are a lot of problems, but the most important one is keeping a global connection object. This should be avoided at all costs because it introduces simple bugs like the one you are experiencing now, but also more subtle problems caused by resources not released to the operating system and leading to very difficult bugs to spot

I would open the SqlConnection just one time enclosing everything in a using statement

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string studentid = Session["student_id"].ToString();
    string i = studentid;
    using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("atend", sc))
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", studentid);
        using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            .... 
           while (rdr.Read())
           {
              ...
              dataRow["Total Lectures"] = gettotalatlectures(sc, subject, studentid);
              dataRow["Attend Lectures"] = getattendance(sc, subject, studentid);
              table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
           }
      }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();   
}

public int getattendance(SqlConnection sc, string sub, string rollno)
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select active from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'",sc))
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       .....
    }
    return present;
}
public int gettotalatlectures(SqlConnection sc, string sub, string rollno)
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from attendance where a_user_id='rollno' AND a_subject_code='sub'", sc))
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        return x;
    }
}
```

In this way, in the page load you create and open the connection, use it and pass it to the methods that requires it. The using statement will also close and dispose the connection (and other disposable objects like the SqlCommand and the SqlDataReader) when exiting from the using block, ALSO in case of exceptions

Notice that this code is executed at every callback because you don't have a check on IsPostback, but this is another story.

Comment: then you still open a lot of queries, running at the same time, lockin a lot of data (possibly)

Comment: Sure, but we cannot know from the code above if it is possible to avoid it. If the poster shows the actual code of the stored procedure probably a complete reenginering of the solution is possible.

Comment: my suggestion indeed. So many problems can be avoided by writing decent T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved Just simple changing in web.config file 
i add in connectionstring **MultipleActiveResultSets=True** and the code run successfully...